# Add panel and controls dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on hotel booking web site, need to write all active bookings in panels with buttons and labels in each of them
This piece of code works properly

```
'creo un pannello per ogni pratica
Dim p1 As New Panel
topd = 270 + 220 * x  ' parto da 270 poi altezza 200 e 20 px di distanza con pannello successivo
p1.Attributes.Item("style") = "top:" & topd & "px; left:50px; z-index: 1; position: absolute; height: 200px; width: 600px;runat: server"
p1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Silver
p1.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1)
p1.Width = Unit.Pixel(600)
p1.Height = Unit.Pixel(200)
p1.ID = "P_" & pratica
Me.Controls.Add(p1)
'nel pannello metto la label di descrizione
Dim l1 As New Label
l1.Attributes.Item("style") = "Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 10px; LEFT: 10px; height: 150px; width:250px; Font-Size:9pt; text-align:center"
l1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
l1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
l1.Text = rosso & testo(22) & sp & npratica & SPANFINE & sr
l1.Text += "Hotel " & preno(1) & sr & testo(24) & sp & preno(4) & sr & testo(25) & sp & preno(5) & sr
l1.Text += testo(28) & sp & preno(10) & sr & testo(26) & sp & preno(6) & sr & testo(27) & sp & preno(7) & sr
l1.Text += testo(29) & sp & preno(11) & sr
l1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
p1.Controls.Add(l1)
```

This works

Now for test I want to add a button and I add the following

```
b1.Text = "prova"
p1.Controls.Add(b1)
```

I get this error

> Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

If I cancel label and add button only I get the same error. If I put panel in html (don't create it dynamically) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ops I found it sorry.

```
Me.Controls.Add(p1)
```

is wrong I have to add to form1

```
form1.Controls.Add(p1)
```

I think I should keep this on stack, maybe can help